# Document clustering from ordered pages list

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-networks, image-recognition

I have a series of ordered pdf pages which own to different documents. Let me give you an example:

Pages: 1 2 3 4 5 6

True Pages: 1 2 | 1 2 3 4

So I have like six ordered pages, two of which from document A, and the remaining from document B. I do not have documents labels so the grouping should be done in an unsupervised way.

Which could be a reasonable approach? Using only CNN to detect border pages shouldn't be enough to discern documents, so I was thinking to something like RNN->CNN or CNN->RNN but I don't know how it would practically work because it is the first time I don't use labels in my TF model.

Do you think it would be a reasonable idea?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE. To give an idea of what your actual question is, you could please put your main **specific** question in the title?

Comment: I tried but I don't know whether this problem has a specific name